# Neither "Photo2Shape", nor "Geotag and import photos" works

Tags: qgis, photos, geotag, photo2shape, exifread

**System**:

- Windows 7
- QGIS 2.6 Brighton and QGIS 2.8 Wien
- Photo2Shape 0.5.0
- EXIFread 2.0.1
- Geotag and import photos 1.1.0
- EXIFtool 9.90

**Problem**:

EXIFtool and EXIFread are installed correctly. Both plugins are installed without any errors. But when I try to geotag some photos, nothing happens. I keeps working without progress. QGIS doesn't crash. I'm able to save and restart it.
I really tried and read all!
Anbody who can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it!

As there are some with the same problem in the web, I will tell you how I solved it, although it's very embarrassing.

Just unmark the box "Append to existing file" ... then it works.

Comment: For me, this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ImportPhotos Plug-in. It doesn't need any third party applications (like EXIFtool) to work. 
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImportPhotos/